# using "project" with "select" in gremlin-javascript is throwing error

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a simple query which gives me expected result when i run it on console, but fails when i run it in aws-neptune DB using gremlin node.js driver/ gremlin-javascript.

query running successfully in console

```
g.V().hasLabel('item').project('id').by(id).select(values)
==>[item1]
==>[item2]
==>[item3]
```

I tried to ran same query in gremlin-javascript using import  "gremlin.process.t"

```
g.V().hasLabel('item').project('id').by(gremlin.process.t.id).select(gremlin.process.t.values)
```

But i get following error "detailedMessage":"null:select([null])"}

```
error Error: Server error: {"requestId":"0521e945-04fb-4173-b4fe-0426809500fc","code":"InternalFailureException","detailedMessage":"null:select([null])"} (599)
```

What is the correct way to use project with select in gremlin-javascript ??

Answer (score 2):

Note that `values` is not on `T` it's on `Column`:

```
gremlin> values.class
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Column$2
```

Therefore, you need to reference that enum in Javascript:

```
const t = gremlin.process.traversal.t
const c = gremlin.process.traversal.column
g.V().hasLabel('item').
  project('id').
    by(t.id).
  select(c.values)
```

You can read about common imports for gremlin-javascript [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_common_imports_2).